# Deleting from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I just uploaded imaged to a users account and know I'm trying to delete one of them, however when I click the delete button it just refreshes the page

this is the code in profile.php that links it to the delete.php

```
echo '<li><a href="delete.php? file_id=<?php echo $file_id;?>">Delete</a> <a href="edit.php? file_id=<?php echo $file_id;?>">Edit</a> <a href="download.php? user_id=<?php echo $file_id;?>">Download</a> </li>';
```

and this is my delete.php:

```
<?php

include("db/connect.php");

include("profile.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users DELETE upload WHERE user_id = file_id";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: You're already in PHP and echoing, why are you `<?php echo`'ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn your code with fire. Burn it! It is ALL wrong!

### 1: Echoing a variable

If you're in the middle of echoing some text and you want a variable, don't try opening a second PHP block, that's not going to work. Instead:

```
echo 'something ' . $variable . ' more text';
```

### 2: Destructive actions with GET

Never, EVER use `<a href="...">` to perform destructive actions, especially not deletion. EVER. You should use a form instead, like this:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="file_id" value="<?php echo $file_id; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete file" />
</form>
```

Bonus points if you add something like `onSubmit="return confirm('Are you SURE you want to delete this?');"` or similar.

### 3: Your delete query

Not sure how you can mess this up, but apparently...

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `upload` WHERE `file_id` = ".intval($_POST['file_id']);
```

You may want to (read: ABSOLUTELY SHOULD!) add some code to check if the current user actually has permission to delete the given file, unless you want people deleting everything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform two queries like this -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users DELETE upload WHERE file_id = file_id";
```

Change it to this -

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM upload WHERE file_id = file_id";
```

I'm unsure how you're passing variables around and I am assuming that you're binding `file_id` properly.

Comment: Words are easier said when chained together, rather than code. If it were only that simple.

Comment: I added a comment under OP's question.